# Getting textbox value on the same page but different php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have this main page that loads another php file on `onchange` event of the dropdown. I use this to load the page:

```
function get_value(){
    if($("#dropdwn").val()=="0"){
        //load nothing
    }else{
        $('#txtval').val($("#dropdown").val());
        $('#load_page').html('<p align="center"><br/><img src="images/popuploader.gif" /><br/><br/></p>');
        $('#load_page').load('load_xml.php');
    }
}
```

For now I put the value of dropdown on the textbox but will also try to get the value of dropdown.
The problem is on the second php file that loads on the main page. I can't get the value of `$txtval=$_POST['txtval']` when I use this. I will need the value for if else condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to sent the parameter to the resource `load_xml.php`.

```
function get_value() {
    if ($("#dropdwn").val() == "0") {
        //load nothing
    } else {
        var val = $("#dropdown").val();
        $('#txtval').val(val);
        $('#load_page').html('<p align="center"><br/><img src="images/popuploader.gif" /><br/><br/></p>');
        $('#load_page').load('load_xml.php?txtval=' + val);
    }
}
```

The the `load` method uses a `GET` request, not a `POST` method.

```
$txtval=$_GET['txtval']
```

---

If you want to sent a POST method, then use the syntax

```
function get_value() {
    if ($("#dropdwn").val() == "0") {
        //load nothing
    } else {
        var val = $("#dropdown").val();
        $('#txtval').val(val);
        $('#load_page').html('<p align="center"><br/><img src="images/popuploader.gif" /><br/><br/></p>');
        $('#load_page').load('load_xml.php?', {
            txtval: val
        });
    }
}
```

then

```
$txtval=$_POST['txtval']
```